# Alternative to synonym search over AWS managed Elasticsearch instance

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working a search implementation wherein I have to use the synonym filter but the challenge I am facing here is how do I make it dynamic, I can not pass the filters in the mapping itself. I need some way to externalize it. But apparently, its not supported in the AWS managed version.

Is there any other way I can do it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to some very old forum, the support for synonyms file via S3 is there in AWS Elasticsearch.

[Check here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html) for reference.

Comment: I missed that completely. Thanks.